# Silverlight RichtextBox Xaml Property, cannot set value (exception)

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hi I want to set the Xaml property of my silverlight richtext box.

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
  richTextBox1.Xaml = "<Paragraph>Blah</Paragraph>";
});
```

However I get the following exception..

```
System.ArgumentException: value
   at System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox.set_Xaml(String value)
```

Can anybody explain this ?
Maybe I am not in the

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. The help page for the RichTextBox does not give any clues on how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.xaml(VS.95).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You actually want to add an XML namespace to the string, so that the Paragraph object can be resolved. Like:

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

As you really only want a single xmlns entry, surround it with a Section block. Your complete working string will be this:

```
richTextBox1.Xaml = "<Section xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"><Paragraph>Blah</Paragraph></Section>";
```

To work this out, I entered text into a RichTextBox (e.g. "Blah") and then viewed the textbox1.Xaml property *(always investigate using working methods first to see what comes out of it)*.